# php interface inheritance of const

Tags: php

I want to do something like this in PHP:

```
interface trollTypeInterface
{
    // ????
    public function scareNaughtyKids()
}
interface trollFrozenInterface extends trollTypeInterface
{
    const COLOR = "lightblue and white"
    public function changeSnowColorToYellow();
}
interface trollForestInterface extends trollTypeInterface
{
    const COLOR = "bronze and green"
    public function cleanUpHollowInTheTree();
}

interface trollUfoInterface extends trollTypeInterface
{
    //forgotten const COLOR should cause error
}
```

How to tell, that all interfaces born from parent `trollTypeInterface` must to have got const `COLOR`?? and generate error if color is not declared? I want to have got 100% of confidence that I can use this Const, when I run RandomFunction(trollTypeInterface $troll);

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have abstract constant. The cleanest solution is to replace `COLOR` constant by method like `getColor()` and make it abstract.

Comment: Read it again. OP asks for **abstract** constant, not constant defined in interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in PHP. You can force classes to implement method but not to set variable or const.